# Ggplot not functioning with historical databse

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to plot with ggplot but it is getting wrong:

The database:

[image]

```
      date_1 <- as.POSIXct(c("2016-01-01"))
      p <- ggplot(historico_numeros_eurusd_3[historico_numeros_eurusd_3$data_ajustada > date_1,], aes(x = `data_ajustada`, y = `BRL/EUR-Venda`))
      d <- p + #geom_line(data = eia_list_df[eia_list_df$date>date_2,], aes(date, value), stat = "identity", colour="#CC0000", size = 1, linetype = "dashed") +
      geom_bar(data = historico_numeros_eurusd_3[historico_numeros_eurusd_3$data_ajustada > date_1,], aes(data_ajustada, `BRL/EUR-Venda`), stat = "identity", colour = "#003399", size = 1) +
ylab("EUR/BRL") + scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%y/%m"))
```

Plotted image:

[image]

Could you help me out?

Comment: What specifically is the problem  - what should your output be?

Comment: What do you want to do ? Could you please give us the row data in code section in order to test ?

Comment: Is your y-variable numeric or a factor/character vector? Use `dput(head(historico_numeros_eurusd_3))` to make the problem reproducible.

Comment: @geryan the idea was to put out a line chart showing the fx-rates.

Comment: @RichardTelford The y variable is a data.frame and the x ("data_ajustada" which is the dates) is in POSIXct format

Comment: `BRL/EUR-Venda` is a factor